On Forming an LLC in a State with Greater Privacy Protection
I live in Virginia and plan on starting a small LLC publishing company.
For privacy reasons, I would like to establish the LLC, in either Delaware or Wyoming which does not require the name nor the address of the founder on the application. Instead, it seems that the name and address of a registered representative will suffice.
Here's what I would like to do:

Form the LLC in one of the two states; say, Delaware. Then, I would like to upload the LLC's books  from a home computer to say, Amazon and/or IngramSpark, which will subsequently print the books on demand as the orders come in. I would like the books to contain the name of my LLC, say, "MY COMPANY," as well as the town in which I have resided of late, say Galax, VA.

I anticipate that profits from this endeavor will be reported to the IRS on Schedule C of the 1040, and thus, carry over as part of Virginia Taxable income to be taxed again by the state of Virginia.
Virginia will get their income tax from me no matter in which state I form the LLC.
Hence---
I ask may I do such a thing --- list in the books a Virginia connection to the company (i.e., MY COMPANY, Galax, VA) yet form the LLC in Delaware or Wyoming which does not require my actual name an address, but rather, those of the registered representative?

Your belief that only a few states offer the desired level of privacy protection isn't true. Almost all of them do (but not NYS). The premise of the question is fundamentally wrong. Also, while there are benefits for publicly held companies in being located in Delaware, @Barmar is incorrect in believing that the benefits are shared for privately held LLCs which Delaware is only notable for allowing you to do things that no one in their right mind would do like eliminating all legal duties of managers to the company. Delaware is also one of the most expensive states to form in.

Ugh! Perhaps someone will simply address the question asked.

Rephrased: Can I list a Virginia location whilst incorporating in another state or will Virginia want me to register with them as some sort of a foreign LLC?

You are supposed to list an address in the state you incorporate in. @Jethro

@Tak Wyoming, Delaware allows the address of the registered representative. Other states (most) do not. Did I not allude to that in the post?

We know. Many companies do that.

Representative means you do not have to list your own name, if you want to keep it private. @Jethro

Take doesn't know what he (or she) is talking about and likes to spout advice without having any basis for it. Don't take Tak seriously.

@ohwilleke So I have gathered.

As with other US states, Virginia requires a foreign LLC to register and have a certificate of authority before operating in the state (see here).
As such, if you operate in Virginia (including being a Virginia resident while transacting business on behalf of the LLC), it doesn't matter where your LLC is domiciled - you'll have to register with Virginia.
This is true for most US states.
However, you might not need to disclose who owns the LLC on the foreign LLC registration form if you hire an agent to perform the action of registration and being your registered agent for you.
You will still need to put the official office address for the company in part II (which will likely be your home address, unless you rent an office somewhere):

II Principal Office
The principal office is the location of the company’s principal
executive offices. Unless the information is available electronically,
the company must keep a current list of its members and other
internal company records at the principal office. A post office box,
by itself, is not allowed.


+1 Thank you for your answer. But does uploading a book to Amazon from one's home computer in Virginia constitute "transacting business in Virginia?" I have not been able to ascertain an answer to that. Any insight you can provide is appreciated.

I tried to upvote your answer but the system wouldn't let me. Sorry. Perhaps my question has attracted too many downvoters :)

But does uploading a book to Amazon from one's home computer in Virginia constitute "transacting business in Virginia?" - As a Virginia resident, you're performing an activity on behalf of the LLC while being in Virginia. So yes, it does. I assume you also spent some time writing that book, presumably also in Virginia?

O.K., yet truly, if one did not form the LLC, he could upload such a book and pay VA tax on  the royalties. However, one would not have the liability protection offered by an LLC. That is why I originally thought I might be able to register the company in Delaware or Wyoming without having to register as a foreign LLC in VA. Thank you for your insightful comment.

@Jethro You might want to check this post about liability protection. You may have an unreasonable expectation.

Many thanks for providing this link.

Thanks again for your answer, which seems to be confirmed by  https://www.marketwatch.com/guides/business/best-state-form-llc/#:~:text=While%20there%20are%20no%20specific,Delaware%20as%20their%20incorporation%20state. (See: Number One Choice Home State)
